# HTML Purifier - Escape disallowed tags instead of stripping

Tags: php, htmlpurifier, html-sanitizing

I'm using HTML Purifier to sanitize user input. I have a list of allowed elements configured, which means that any tag not in the allowed list is stripped. Code below:

```
require_once "HTMLPurifier.standalone.php";
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.AllowedElements', array('strong','b','em','i'));
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$safe_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html));
```

Rather than only retaining their contents, I would like the elements that are not included in the list to be escaped and sent back as text.

---

To illustrate, given the white list shown above, the following input string:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('XSS')"><strong>CLAIM YOUR PRIZE</strong></a>
```

turns into `"<strong>CLAIM YOUR PRIZE</strong>"`, because `a` is not whitelisted. Similarly,

```
<b>Check the article <a href="http://example.com/">here</a></b>
```

becomes `"<b>Check the article here</b>"`.

Is there a way to turn the above two examples into the following:

```
&lt;a href="javascript:alert('XSS')"&gt;<strong>CLAIM YOUR PRIZE</strong>&lt;/a&gt;
```

```
<b>Check the article &lt;a href="http://example.com/"&gt;here&lt;/a&gt;</b>
```

purely by adjusting HTML Purifier's configuration *without resorting to regular expression-based "hacks"*? If there is, then I'd like to know how it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting `Core.EscapeInvalidTags` should be what you're looking for:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php');

$dirty_html = '<a href="javascript:alert(\'XSS\')"><strong>CLAIM YOUR PRIZE<div></div></strong></a>';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.AllowedElements', array('strong','b','em','i'));
$config->set('Core.EscapeInvalidTags', true);
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$safe_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);

echo $safe_html . PHP_EOL;
```

...gives:

```
&lt;a href="javascript:alert('XSS')"&gt;<strong>CLAIM YOUR PRIZE&lt;div /&gt;</strong>&lt;/a&gt;
```

I threw in the invalid child element `<div></div>` there so you can see what happens: HTML Purifier will still 'alter' the original HTML due to parsing it (`<div></div>` becomes `<div />`), but the information remains (and is converted to `&lt;div /&gt;`).